# Обработка нажатия на график MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android

Имеется график, построенный с помощью библиотеки [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при нажатии выводилась информация о столбце (х, у). Как сделать?

```
barChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```